# How to break the string into two lines in ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, string, xpath

How to break the string into two lines in ruby code?
Is there specific symbol?

```
def my_def
  path = "//div/p[contains(., 'This is a veeeeeeeryyyyyy looooonggggg string')]"
end
```

I wish to make something like that:

```
def my_def
  path = "//div/p[contains(., 'This is a veeeeeeeryyyyyy
          looooonggggg string')]"
end
```

[image]
Back slashes doesn't work right!

Comment: Had trouble doing this in Pry.  Try this in a plain text editor and run it from the console.

Comment: Please don't use images to show us important information in a question. We can't copy/paste the information, nor can search engines index it to help others find your question. Plus links rot and break. Instead copy/paste the information into your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby will automatically concatenate two strings that are adjacent:

```
foo = 'a' 'b'
foo  # => "ab"
```

Normally a line-end signifies the end of the assignment:

```
foo = 'a'
      'b'
foo  # => "a"
```

so you can't simply break the lines and expect Ruby to figure out what to do.

`\` marks the line as continuing, so you could use:

```
foo = "a" \
      "b"
foo # => "ab"
```

Or, rely on the `+` String concatenation:

```
foo = 'a' +
      'b'
foo # => "ab"
```

I'd probably use the `+` since it's most often used to join strings already, so its meaning is very obvious. Using `\` leads to people joining really long expressions instead of breaking them down.

If your strings are *really* long, you can use some other tricks:

```
foo = [
  'foo',
  'bar'
].join
foo  # => "foobar"
```

If you want to join the strings with a space, such as recombining sentences:

```
foo = [
  'foo',
  'bar'
].join(' ')
foo  # => "foo bar"
```

or:

```
foo = [
  'foo',
  'bar'
] * ' '
foo  # => "foo bar"
```

Building on all that, I'd use some combination of the above or simply something like:

```
long_str = 'This is a veeeeeeeryyyyyy' +
           ' looooonggggg string'
path = "//div/p[contains(., '#{ long_str }')]"
```

or:

```
long_str = [
  'This is a veeeeeeeryyyyyy',
  'looooonggggg string'
].join(' ')
path = "//div/p[contains(., '%s')]" % long_str
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a backward slash to indicate the string continues on the next line, like so:

```
str = "this is a long \
string"

print str # => this is a long string
```

If your string gets way too big, it might be a good idea to use here docs instead. They allow you to write pieces of text in the middle of the code:

```
str = <<HEREDOC
This is my string :)
Let's imbue code in the imbued doc: #{[4, 2, 3, 1].sort}
HEREDOC

print str
# => This is my string :)
# => Let's imbue code in the imbued doc: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`HEREDOC` can be any name you want to give it. You can learn more about [here docs here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc).

Comment: Back slashes doesn't work as I expected! As an example I attached a picture for you.

Comment: @andgursky Did you try to run the code with the backslashes? The image you showed looks like a bug in the highlighting program you use, but the program should run just fine.